# Prove that P(A)=P(B)=P(A,B) if A and B are independent Eg. P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)

Tags: probability

(1) P(A|B)=P(A)
(2) P(B|A)=P(B)
(3) P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)

How can I prove that (1)=(2)=(3) if A and B are independent ?? I just started learning about Bayes' Theorem and i am still very unfamiliar with the theorem. I do understand the 3 definitions above, but i dont see how P(A) can be equivalent to P(B) and also P(A,B). I do know that P(A) does not have any affect on the occurance of P(B).

Comment: It is not true that $P(A)=P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ when $A,B$ are independent.

Comment: And how you define that A and B are independent?

Comment: You just asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797601/is-there-any-way-to-prove-that-pa-pb-pa-b-if-a-and-b-are-indepen) a few minutes ago.  At that time, it was pointed out to you that you should include the definition of independence that you are using.

Comment: @lulu hi there, sorry if i didnt catch that previously. Will edit and add that in.

Comment: I think you also misunderstand what it is you are meant to prove.  You certainly aren't asked to show that $P(A)=P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ for general, independent, events.  You should easily be able to generate counterexamples to that.  Rather you are asked to prove that these three conditions are all equivalent to each other and that they are all true when $A,B$ are independent.

Comment: If $P(A) = 0$ then 1 and 3 are true but what about 2?  How do zero probability events play into the concept of independence?

Answer (score 2):

The three statements that you give are three possible definitions of what it means to say that events $A$ and $B$ are independent.

We know that

$P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)$

You can use this to show that $(1) \Rightarrow (2) \Rightarrow (3) \Rightarrow (1)$. In other words, if we assume $(1)$ is true then so is $(2)$; if we assume $(2)$ is true then so is $(3)$ etc. So the three definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

> but i dont see how P(A) can be equivalent to P(B) and also P(A,B)

Well, it obviously isn't and nowhere in the three definitions you quoted is such implied.

I think you are misunderstanding

3. $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$

$P(A,B)$ means the probability of both $A$ and $B$ occurring (which is sometimes written as $P(A\cap B)$)  is $P(A)$ multiplied by $P(B)$.   It seems you interpreted it as "$P(A,B) = P(A)$ or $P(B)$" .... which is just plain nutty.

Those three statements are the *definition* of "independent" and you can not prove a definition. For example:  If I said "the definition of  fezzgabnot is a yellow sponge soaked in milk; now prove that" that would be a ridiculous task. The only reason a fezzgabnot is a yellow sponge soaked in milk is because we *said* it was, and the only way to prove a yellow sponge soaked in milk is a fezzgabnot is to agree that "fezzgabnot" is the word we use for a yellow sponge soaked in milk.

Now if I said "The definition of a square is a rectangle with equal sides, now prove a square is a rectangle with equal sides" that make no sense but if I side "The definition of a square is a rectangle with equal sides, now prove a square is a rhombus with equal angles" that be a legitimate question.

But what if I ran into someone who says "wait, when I went to school, *I* learned that a square was a rhombus with equal angles; there's nothing to prove".  And person three says "No, *my* definition of a square is a regular polygon with four sides" and we quibble and decide we nee a formal definition but we can agree which is the most basic so we say

Definition:  A *square* is

1. A rectangle with equal sides
2. A rhombus with equal angles
3. A regular polygon with four sides

Okay.... but how can a *definition* have three *different* statements.  Aren't those statements completely different things.  Well, no, they are all the exact *same* thing.  But to accept they are the same thing we must prove they are.

.....

So the *definition* of *independent* events are:

> Def:  Events $A$ and $B$ are said to be independent if

1. $P(A|B)=P(A)$
2. $P(B|A)=P(B)$
3. $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$.

But if we have a definition we must prove that those three statements all meant the same thing.

And we prove that with our basic identity that

> $P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)$.

So if 1) is true and $P(A|B)= P(A)$ then $P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(A)P(B)$ so 3) is true

So $1)\implies 3)$.

And if 2) is true and $P(B|A) = P(B)$ then $P(A\cap B) = P(B|A)P(A) = P(B)P(A)$ so 3) is true

So $2)\implies 3).

ANd if 3) is true and $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, then we *also* have $P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)$.   So $P(A)P(B) = P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)$.

So if $P(A) \ne 1$ then  $P(B) = \frac {P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)} = P(B|A)$ and 2) is true.

If $P(A) =0$ then $P(A|B)=0=P(A)$ and $1$ is true.  But $P(B|A)$ is not a valid expression so, I guess, $P(B|A) =P(B)$ is vacuously true.  (I think......   or maybe the definition should be 2) $P(B|A) =P(B)$ *when defined*.  Or maybe independent event don't apply for zero probability events and should have been stipulated in the definition)

And if $P(B) \ne 1$ then $P(A) =P(A|B) = \frac {P(A|B)P(A)}{P(B)}$ and 2) is true.

ANd if $P(B) = 1$ we have the same issues.

So assuming $P(A)\ne 0; P(B) \ne 0$. we have

1. implies 3)
2. implies 3)
3. implies 1) and 2)

SO all three are equivalent.

It makes sense to me that zero probability events are either independent with all events or with no events but the definition should take one of those into account but didn't.  I'll concede to whoever has studied statistics more recently than I have.